# calling some online service from GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I have this JavaScript code which is connecting with the service and sending back the result.

Now the requirement is to call the same service from Pure Java.

Below is the javascript code for calling the service.

If some one can guide me to convert this Javascript to Java in my GWT Application

Thanks

```
         function verifyValidationSyntax(textToValidate)

         {   
         var url = "https://validation-grammar.example.com/validation_grammar_service/rest/validation_step_validation";  
         var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
         client.open("POST", url, false);
         client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
         client.send(textToValidate);
         if (client.responseText==='true') {
         return "true";
         } else {
        return "false";
        }

      }
```

Answer (score 2):

I wont convert your code, But here is the sweetest example from [`docs`](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html)

```
String url = "http://www.myserver.com/getData?type=3";
RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, URL.encode(url));

try {
  Request request = builder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {
    public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
       // Couldn't connect to server (could be timeout, SOP violation, etc.)
    }

    public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
      if (200 == response.getStatusCode()) {
          // Process the response in response.getText()
      } else {
        // Handle the error.  Can get the status text from response.getStatusText()
      }
    }
  });
} catch (RequestException e) {
  // Couldn't connect to server
}
```

You may miss this in docs

> To use the HTTP types in your application, you'll need to first inherit the GWT HTTP module by adding the following  tag to your module XML file:

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.http.HTTP" />
```

Comment: thanks ,  Response cannot be resolved to a type.Dont see any import suggestion for that , please guide

Comment: http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/http/client/Response.html

Comment: Thanks .. when i run i get this error :  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.google.gwt.http.client.URL.encodeImpl(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

Comment: No idea weather it allow https or not. have you tried any other example with some http link ?

Comment: http://validation-grammar.devfactory.com/validation_grammar_service/rest/validation_step_validation                      trying this link ,giving the same erro

Comment: Try to hit that url in browser and see.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44670/discussion-between-junaidp-and-ss-)